# "Flash (one's attention/eyes)" for "focus/direct (one's attention/eyes)", and "flash one's eyes at" for "stare with lust or passion at"

Tags: word-usage, dialects, colloquialisms

As far as your English variety goes, is it acceptable in every which register of speech and writing, and rather common usage, to say "flash" for "focus/direct (one's attention/eyes)", but also for "display/expose (a certain feeling)"?

Likewise, is it okay to say "flash one's eyes at someone" to mean to stare at someone with a glow of fire in one's eyes?

E.g.

[*They **flashed their eyes** at one another like teens*...](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=fqKAyHu4cWcC&pg=PT13&lpg=PT13&dq=%22flashed+their+eyes+at%22&source=bl&ots=DfO4mRDyD-&sig=SLfgYCStHNPelRgVG8zCQCxX-rk&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=u_4NU7XPEYmN0AXRkYDACQ&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22flashed%20their%20eyes%20at%22&f=false)

[*The tigers and wildcats glared and **flashed their eyes** at each other*...](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1913&dat=19001001&id=pdcgAAAAIBAJ&sjid=C2sFAAAAIBAJ&pg=4560,3302670)

[*And **flashed their eyes** at cruel but fundamentally decent counts*...](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/01/23/magazine/23lives-t.html?_r=0)

[*I **flashed my eyes** at him*...](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/01/23/magazine/23lives-t.html?_r=0)

[*Grandma Terrant **flashed her eyes** on her watch*...](http://www.stlcop.edu/news/publications/Complete%20ConjuRxings%20Spring%202007.pdf)

[*Sissy and Mom **flashed their eyes** on me...*](http://www.wattpad.com/39004766-my-girlfriend%27s-a-demigod-i-met-a-human-torch)

[*All the other cats **flashed their eyes** on him*...](http://www.ex-christian.net/topic/45899-tromaphona-the-cat/)

[*I was just sitting here working and **flashed my eyes** on your last*...](http://wwwwordsfromwillow.blogspot.fr/2011/11/part-3-wisdom-from-others-mystery-of.html)

[*Hutch **flashed his eyes** on the door*...](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/2682329/1/Falling-Down-The-Rabbit-Hole)

[*Napoli and Bayern Leverkusen have **flashed their interest** in the player*...](http://t.sportige.com/sportige/?ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.br%2F#!/entry/51c555c1da27f5d9d0e5efaa&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fsportige.com%2Ftransfer-rumors-liverpool-trying-to-sign-toby-alderweireld-06-2013%2F&oswts=1393414276023)

[*Both **flashed their attention** to the bird*...](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/1478826/2/Jurassic-Park-III-Rewritten)

Comment: I made your examples hyperlinks again, it really improves the readability of your question.

Comment: Likewise, I fixed your newly added hyperlinks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash seems to indicate that the attention is only momentarily directed at the object, whereas focusing give me a more long-lasting impression.

Even if the focus of attention is only short-lived, it implies some actual involved action from the part of the focuser.

If somebody flashes something I would think they quickly and briefly display something (attention is shown to the bird, interest in the player is shown (to the press?)).

The last meaning is also used when someone quickly shows a sign or banner, or body parts that conventionally remain covered (she flashed her breasts at president Putin).

Notice that your examples are actually quite different from one another:

> The clubs flashed (their interest in the player) (to the press, presumably)
>   The people flashed (their attention) (to the bird)

The added examples with the common phrase "flash" one's eyes can be read the same way: they briefly, quickly turned their eyes in the object's direction.

If one were to **focus** on the object (or focus their eyes / stare) they would definitely do so for a longer time, and more noticeably, more intensely.

Comment: Yes I don't think either definition fits "flash".

Answer (score 1):

this is certainly not common usage, and I have not heard the term 'flash' used in this way before. I would stick with "focus one's attention".

Best wishes,

PME